# Why are ice hockey skates have a hollow gliding surface, while long distant ones have a flat surface?

Tags: friction

I used to do a lot of ice hockey and only now I realise that the surface of my skates was hollow, so the surface of the iron made more or less only contact with the ice with the sharp edges of the hollow area.

Long distance skates, on the other hand, have a flat surface with sharp edges, so those surfaces make more contact with the ice.

Is this because long distance ice skaters go faster when going straight ahead, because of the bigger surface of contact?

Answer (score 1):

Since you glide on the thin water film between the blade and the ice (see [why is ice slippery?](http://lptms.u-psud.fr/membres/trizac/Ens/L3FIP/Ice.pdf)) and as you stated in your question, the shape of the blade changes the surface in contact with the ice. Different shapes will yield different results.

In any case, you go slower but you have way more control on hockey skates and you go way faster but its harder and takes more technique to make turns with speed skates.

Answer (score 0):

The long skates provide better contact surface and thus better energy transfer and greater speeds.  Their larger surface makes it harder to stop or change directly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Skates ground hollow exert much higher pressure on the ice at their edges: this means the edges cut deeper grooves in the ice which give you much greater grip perpendicular to the skate.  So you can turn, start and stop really quickly, which is important for ice hockey.  The downside is that the very sharp edges will displace the water film meaning you get higher friction, especially if the skate is not flat on the ice.

Skates ground flat have much worse grip, but lower friction as the blunter edges don't displace water so aggressively.